# Visualizing GeoServer web map in other computers of company?

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wms

I made a Leaflet web map that I have no problem visualizing in my computer. It is a simple web map that contains a basemap and a few shapefiles (it's only use is to visualize the spatial data and when clicking, show some attributes), served from Geoserver on my computer.

Everything works just as intended, but now I want other people in my company to be able to use it. The problem is that when they enter the web map, they see the basemap ('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png') but not the shapefiles, so it is clear that the shapefiles are not in the right place.

I am using Geoserver with Tomcat, and I have the shapefiles in my computer. The data directory in Geoserver is "C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.14.1\data_dir", where the shapefiles are.

My guess is that when they enter the web map, they don't have access to my "C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.14.1\data_dir" and that is why they don't see the shapefiles.

Is there some way to save the shapefiles in geoserver/tomcat so everyone can visualize them, or another way to deal with this?

It sounds like some basic knowledge, but I am a beginner with geoserver, tomcat and webmapping and I have been searching for days without success.

I have also tried to put the shapefiles in a shared folder and set the shapefile directory of the Geoserver Store as that folder, but that doesn't solve the problem either.

Next, I'm showing part of the code, as required in the comments. Everyone sees the OpenStreetMaps basemap, but no one except me sees the 'Mun' layer, from Geoserver.

```
var osm = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'OpenStreetMaps',
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);


var mun = L.tileLayer.betterWms("http://" + serv + ":8089/geoserver/mex/wms?", {
    layers: 'Mun',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    opacity:0.3,
    version: '1.1.0',
    attribution: "Geoserver"
    }).addTo(map)
```

Comment: Leaflet tag was removed since question is not related to Leaflet but to Geoserver.

Comment: leaflet tag added back, this is to do with how leaflet sees a WMS layer

Comment: please edit the question with the relevant part of your leaflet javascript file where you add the wms layer.

Comment: @IanTurton Edited. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: is your firewall open for port 8089? try just connecting to GeoServer from a colleagues machine

Comment: @IanTurton Yes, they can connect to GeoServer.

Comment: is there an error in the geoserver log file?

Comment: What's the value of the `serv` variable in your javascript code? (and please don't tell me it's `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`). Also, look for errors using the browser's developer tools (hit F12), specifically the network tab.

Comment: @IvanSanchez The value is my private IP.

Comment: You answered that other users can connect to server. Did they try to use WMS service that is based on your shapefiles?